# IPtables keeps resetting rules and blocking almost everything

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables

Every time I reset IPtables, the rules keep coming back in about 10 minutes, blocking everything besides port 22 and 80.

When I do a "iptables-save", [I see this](http://pastebin.com/cNNTpV1s)

I can't find out where it's coming from. I'm running CentOS 6.5 on a dedicated server at Hetzner.de

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"?

Comment: When I set my own rules, the rules go back the way they ware in the pastebin and no connections can be made

Comment: OK, check with my answer bellow please and tell us if it fixes the problem.

Comment: That means, no matter what I set or what I do, IPtables goes back to blocking almost everything

Answer (score 1):

Iptables resets everytime when you reboot your system so you need to load it automatically on every boot, for that you can:

```
sudo sh -c "iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules"
```

*This will dump your rules into a file.*

Then make another script who will run on startup:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0
```

*Plus you can make the scripts autorun every 10 min or so, as you wish, but iptables doesn't reset until service is restarted.*

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way to do so is the following:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Comment: I tried, after less than 5 minutes, it goes back to blocking again

Comment: I believe that you checked for conr jobs right? Is that a production server? If not, can you request for a clean OS re-install from your DC?

Comment: I want it to be a production server. But it can't do the job because it keeps blocking connections. The crontab is empty

Comment: Crontab is not not the only place that you have to look. Disable all non-important services. Actually, disable all services except of SSH and check again. Clean up your server (packages you don't need etc).

Answer (score 0):

Either there's some cron job resetting the rules, or you have some daemon running and that keeps resetting the rules. You should check all running services and stop (and disable) everything you don't need. That's a useful advice even without problems like this - there should not be anything running on your server that you don't know exactly what purpose it serves.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have installed Puppet or something like that. Check out your services, find something like:

Puppet or Chef

Regards,